# PowerPoint Interop - How to access Chart out of a shape?

Tags: charts, interop, powerpoint

I am working in an office automation tool to process PowerPoint documents, where I am facing an issue in formatting Chart.

I am using the following assemblies for formatting the Presentation
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint  Version: 12.0.0.0
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph Version: 12.0.0.0
Requirement is to apply some styles like Legend location, color, font etc to the Chart exists in the presentation.

I am able to verify the Shape like
    shape.HasChart == MsoTriState.msoTrue
But not able to get the Chart object out of the shape

Tried the following code, but received OLEFormat exception
    Graph.Chart chart = (Graph.Chart)shape.OLEFormat.Object

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue by selecting correct reference from the COM tab. 
Answer from thread - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officegeneral/thread/06cea2b7-f169-4f8a-b53e-4319b12b5450

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking from (rather) .NET point of view but I'll show you some code from VBA PowerPoint. My goal is to show you object hierarchy. I believe it would be helpful enough for you to solve your problem.

```
Sub Chart_Elements()

Dim CHRT As Chart
'first shape in the 1st slide is chart
Set CHRT = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart

With CHRT
    'to set legend position
    .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
    'to set size of 1st entry in legend
    .Legend.LegendEntries(1).Font.Size = 10
    'and so on
End With
End Sub
```

If that answer doesn't help you at all please consider re-tagging your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned in the post, I am using the Interop assemblies with version 12, in which I don't have the Chart property for the Shape. shape.Chart is not supported.

Comment: Resolved the issue by selecting correct reference from the COM tab.  Answer from thread - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officegeneral/thread/06cea2b7-f169-4f8a-b53e-4319b12b5450